# Visual C++ for linux 'illegal characters in path' Error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm having problems running C++ programs through Visual C++ for Linux to a Raspberry Pi.

When I first tried a sample running a program, it worked. A couple weeks later, when I tried this again (now) it failed in this error.

The program only uses cstdio library so it should work. I've looked around and some people say it's because g++ can't find libraries or something.

The Error form the Error list is: Exception occurred while copying sources to remote machine - illegal characters in path.

and it also points me to line 162 of Linux.targets, which is:

```
162 <CopySources
163       Sources="@(FinalSourcesToCopyRemotely)"
164       AdditionalSources="@(AdditionalSourcesToCopyRemotely)"
165       ProjectDir="$(ProjectDir)"
166       …(continues on)
```

In the program output, it also says something similar to, 'CopySources - FAILED'

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing that if you determine what `@(FinalSourcesToCopyRemotely)` evaluates to, you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out - The filename/solution name can't have spaces (in my case). (I'm new to this so I am unfamiliar with this stuff.)